# signal handler vs event handler

Tags: c++, linux, windows, events, signals

Recently in an interview they asked me to point out the difference between signal handlers and event handlers. I have never encountered event handlers in Linux but after searching with Google I find event handlers are present in Windows.

I just want some more information regarding this question. Any information is most welcome.

Comment: Signals are cruder and more invasive than events.  GUI programs typically have a main loop that responds to events — in both WinAPI and X11.

Comment: I have edited please correct me @Jonathan Leffler .

Answer (score 0):

I found that user have to write event handler function in order to capture events while default signal handlers are provided by kernel for the program.

Event handlers take care of the events external to the program like keyboard interrupt, mouse click etc. Event handlers would be polling  continuously on a particular slot for the event to happen. So here it might consume the CPU life cycles.

Signal handlers also used for interprocess communication between two process. User can define their own signal handler for the process to handle particular signals. In signal handling mechanism I don't think any CPU cycles are  consumed unnecessarily.

Please correct me if a not heading in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I think signal handlers specific to the events originated from the kernel whereas event handlers are kind of a more abstract version of signal handlers and include 'any' kind of events (clicks events, network events, signals etc.)